# add a new column to the file based on another file

Tags: awk

I  have two files file1 and file2 as shown below. file1 has two columns and file2 has one column. I want to add second column to the file2 based on file1. How can I do this with awk?

file1

```
2WPN  B
2WUS  A
2X83  A
2XFG  A
2XQR  C
```

file2

```
2WPN_1
2WPN_2
2WPN_3    
2WUS
2X83
2XFG_1
2XFG_2
2XQR
```

Desired Output

```
2WPN_1  B
2WPN_2  B
2WPN_3  B    
2WUS    A
2X83    A
2XFG_1  A
2XFG_2  A
2XQR    C
```

your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { t = $1; sub(/_.*$/, "", t); print $1, a[t] }' file1 file2
```

Or

```
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { t = $1; sub(/_.*$/, "", t); printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, a[t] }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
2WPN_1  B
2WPN_2  B
2WPN_3  B
2WUS    A
2X83    A
2XFG_1  A
2XFG_2  A
2XQR    C
```

You may pass output to `column -t` to keep it uniform with spaces and not tabs.